# How to access members of an inner object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm not able to access members of an inner object.

```
class Foo {
    val obj = object {
        val field = 42
    }
}

fun foo() {
    Foo().obj.field // unresolved reference field
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that *obj* is seen as type *Any* outside of its own scope. This means that only obj can reference its own properties because the [Any](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) class doesn't contain any properties.

If instead you had an interface that had a property, and made your object extend that interface and implement the property, you would be able to reference it anywhere that had visibility of that property:

```
interface FieldHolder {
  val field: Int
}

class Foo {
  val obj = object: FieldHolder {
    override val field = 42
  }
}

fun foo() {
  Foo().obj.field // this should now work.
}
```